# how to protect udp packets from packets loss?

Tags: networking, udp

when i tried to ping with mtr using udp pinging i gets packets loss from outside wan

the result of (mtr 8.8.8.8 -s 576 -n -u):

```
 5. 149.6.154.169                                                                                                                                                                                                                 9.5%   465   79.1  86.3  71.8 707.3  47.8
    149.14.126.105
    154.14.64.29
    93.186.129.10
    149.14.125.145
    149.6.155.85
    149.14.124.33
    149.14.124.73
 6. 46.33.86.206                                                                                                                                                                                                                  3.2%   465  107.2  90.7  70.6 754.7  51.2
    93.186.129.21
    154.54.61.30
    154.54.36.70
    72.14.221.78
    93.186.129.25
    93.186.129.23
    130.117.48.205
 7. 195.219.166.196                                                                                                                                                                                                              36.3%   465   91.7  89.4  71.4 663.0  42.5
    72.14.221.145
    72.14.204.72
    108.170.252.225
    130.117.51.138
    72.14.213.156
    72.14.216.154
    130.117.51.74
 8. 209.85.172.66                                                                                                                                                                                                                55.9%   465  100.3  96.9  83.3 732.9  48.6
    72.14.213.156
    195.2.26.25
    66.249.95.55
    72.14.232.49
    8.8.8.8
    172.253.67.155
 9. 195.2.24.130                                                                                                                                                                                                                 91.0%   465  103.5 100.0  84.2 141.0   8.7
    8.8.8.8
    108.170.245.65
    108.170.245.81
10. 8.8.8.8                                                                                                                                                                                                                      92.0%   465  102.3  98.8  83.3 104.5   6.1
    195.89.96.234
    216.239.50.241
```

is there a way to fix this or perhaps reduce it, and also can i change isp route without vpn as vpn increase ping ?

Comment: Your question contains a large list of IP addresses but it is unclear for what purpose and how this list was generated. If you are using a special tool to generate this list please edit your question and name it and also post the complete command you have executed.

Comment: that is my traceroute

Comment: So this question is about reliability of DNS queries? 8.8.8.8 is the Google DNS server. If you want "reliable DNS" you can use DNS over HTTPS or DNS over TLS.

Comment: The packet loss you're getting is because high-end backbone routers are not great ping responders. It doesn't necessarily reflect anything real about traffic passing through them.

Comment: Without really knowing; I wouldn't be too surprised if a DNS - with regard to its normal use - might simply drop any packet **type** that is **outside the normal use**. *(Quick test `mtr 8.8.8.8 -s 576 -n -u` -> huge relative packet loss count/percentage)*

Comment: UDP is the "non-reliable" protocol. It's alot like a post card, send and forget with no receipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP is considered a "connectionless" protocol.
There **is no** guarantee of delivery like there is for TCP.

"UDP **does not provide error correction** and is therefore an **unreliable protocol**. In other words, delivery of packets is not guaranteed. UDP datagrams are transmitted without provision for an acknowledgment. Because there is **no virtual connection between sender and receiver**, UDP is also said to be **connectionless**."

This is by design, and it is usually used for traffic that needs to be delivered/switched as fast as possible.

Using UDP as a measure for packet loss isn't good practice.

Quote is a reference from here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/user-datagram-protocol.
Emphasis is my own.